# Send SOAP Message Object through HttpAsyncClient in Java

Tags: java, asynchronous, soap, nio, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a `SOAP Message` object with `attachments` in Java.Now I am using `TransformerFactory` to convert `SOAPPart` of the message to String and send it with `HttpAsyncClient` post method.Till here it is working fine.
But when I try to send attachment present in SOAPMessage by converting to String and appending to String writer, i get an exception.

attachment is the file I want to send as an attachment.

Below is a snippet of my code

```
        final SOAPMessage message;
        final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        try {
            TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(new DOMSource(message.getSOAPPart()),
                    new StreamResult(sw));
            sw.append("\n");
            TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(new StreamSource(attachment), new StreamResult(sw));
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url.toString());
        HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(sw.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);

        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        post.setConfig(params);
        post.setEntity(entity);
        client.execute(post, new AsyncResponseHandler<>(subscribedUsers, campaignId, path, isOnline,
                CommunicationConstants.EMAIL));
```

Exception I am getting

```
<< "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode><faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 67; columnNumber: 6; The processing instruction target matching &quot;[xX][mM][lL]&quot; is not allowed.</faultstring><detail><ns1:stackTrace xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 67; columnNumber: 6; The processing instruction target matching &quot;[xX][mM][lL]&quot; is not allowed.[\n]"
21:34:48.614 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x9]at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)[\n]"
21:34:48.614 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x9]at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)[\n]"
21:34:48.614 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x9]at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)[\n]"
21:34:48.614 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x9]at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)[\n]"
21:34:48.614 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x9]at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)[\n]"
21:34:48.614 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x9]at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)[\n]"
21:34:48.614 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x9]at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.scanPIData(Unknown Source)[\n]"
21:34:48.614 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x9]at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanPIData(Unknown Source)[\n]"
21:34:48.615 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x9]at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.scanPI(Unknown Source)[\n]"
21:34:48.615 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x9]at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$TrailingMiscDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)[\n]"
21:34:48.615 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x9]at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)[\n]"
21:34:48.615 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x9]at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)[\n]"
21:34:48.615 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x9]at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)[\n]"
21:34:48.615 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x9]at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)[\n]"
21:34:48.615 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x9]at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)[\n]"
21:34:48.615 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x9]at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)[\n]"
21:34:48.615 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x9]at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)[\n]"
21:34:48.615 [I/O dispatcher 1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[0x9]at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)[\n]"
```

My Request String is
I am getting exception in the line 67 where another xml block is starting as it is treatig both of them as separate xmls.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"> <SOAP-ENV:Header><authenticate xmlns="http://webservices.ecircle-ag.com/ws"><realm>rummy_campaign</realm><email>ecircle-tracking@games24x7.net</email><password>Teteda&gt;5</password></authenticate></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body>
   <postGroupRequest xmlns="http://webservices.ecircle-ag.com/ws">
<control xmlns="http://webservices.ecircle-ag.com/ecm" group-id="new" request-id="ccffd43f-df3b-45a0-a36f-9d204c5cabc1">
    <group-definition preferred-channel="email">
        <name>572085adb0a07130f99906c7_1_20160427_27</name>
        <isocountry>IN</isocountry>
        <isolanguage>en</isolanguage>
        <email-channel>
            <!--email address of the cloned group -->
            <email>572085adb0a07130f99906c7_20160427_27@campaigns.rummycircle.com</email>
            <to-handling>
                <recipient/>
            </to-handling>
            <from-handling>
                <special>
                    <email>test@campaigns.rummycircle.com</email>
                    <name>Tester</name>
                </special>
            </from-handling>
            <reply-to-handling>
                <ignore/>
            </reply-to-handling>

        </email-channel>
        <tracking>
            <text link="true"/>
            <html individual-link="false" link="true" pixel-position="bottom" reader="true"/>           
        </tracking>
        <io-control>
            <sendout-speed>9999000</sendout-speed>
            <!-- <bounce count="3" hours="360"/> -->
        </io-control>

    </group-definition>

    <member-list add-mode="add_no_message" sync-mode="replace">
        <uri-reference gzip-compressed="false">recipients572085adb0a07130f99906c75419335757091968787.xml
        </uri-reference>
    </member-list>

    <message message-id="new">
        <!--when should the send-out happen -->
        <send-date>
            <immediately/>
        </send-date>
        <!--where to send reports -->
        <!-- name of the message - used as an identifier in DMC GUI -->
        <name>572085adb0a07130f99906c7_1 Message</name>

        <content target-content-encoding="UTF-8">
            <subject target-encoding="UTF-8">english test async off email path 2</subject>
            <!-- <text target-content-encoding="ISO-8859-1">textual version</text> -->
            <!-- please make sure to escape any html entities -->
            <html target-content-encoding="UTF-8">english test async off email path 2</html>
        </content>
    </message>

    <!-- where to send success and failure reports -->

    <delete-date>

        <in>PT5M</in>
    </delete-date>
</control></postGroupRequest>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><userdata xmlns="http://webservices.ecircle-ag.com/ecm">
    <list>
        <user>
            <email>khushboo.sangal@games24x7.com</email>
        </user>
    </list>
</userdata>
```

Comment: please provide the exception you got

Comment: Could you please post the whole exception stack trace into your question?